# CSCore: is it possible to create parallel source chains?

Tags: cscore

I'm developing an application in which I'd like to play a sound and also visualize that sound in various ways. In the visualizer portion I want to apply some filters to extract different features of the sound, but not affect the sound which is played.

```
Source-->WasapiOut
      -->HighpassFilter-->HighpassVisualizationOutput
      -->LowpassFilter-->LowpassVisualizationOutput
```

Is it possible to construct several synchronized chains in this manner, or am I thinking about this problem wrong?